# PHP cURL, sometimes this error: The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the error: Connection timed out after 8001 milliseconds

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with my code in PHP.
I use the cURL for loading file, I can not use file_get_contents in the hosting.

The problem is randomly, many time works fine and sometime doesn't work, the returned error is:
The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the error:
Connection timed out after 8001 milliseconds.

The php code in the method It is this:

```
    $url = self::DIREZIONESITO . "/vista/" . $nombreFichero;

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        return $res;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: seems like it's a response time issue. the requested url takes too much time to response.

Answer (score -1):

If your script sometimes work fine and sometimes bad, maybe the issue will be external to your script. If you want, you can give a "time out" upper playing with CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT parameter. [curl_setopt() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)